# Visually irritating spacing in enum(erate/item), item and task lists

Tags: lists

[image]

The spacing between the right-most points of the "f" character and the right bracket is extremely irritating. Is there a universal way to rewrite the spacing specifically for the character "f"? Ideally there should be an additional space in the printed form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's by design. When TeX typesets `(f)`, it does

```
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
....\kern0.77779
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
```

where the kern is implicit (there is no space after `\kern` in the symbolic output) and is established in the font metrics. The amount of kerning is the same as the italic correction for “f” in the font, namely 0.77779pt.

I see no particularly irritating spacing. There is if you do `\ref` to the item labeled as (f), though, because of how this is implemented.

Anyway, you can try and add twice the italic correction.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
\item
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \setcounter{enumii}{4}
  \item
  \item
  \end{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*\kern2\fontcharic\font\numexpr`a-1+\arabic*\relax)]
  \setcounter{enumii}{4}
  \item
  \item\label{x}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{x}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To be honest, I find the second example worse than the first one.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I do not like the original either. Some amount between 1 to 2 times the spacing is what I am after.

Comment: @JackTigerLam Change 2 into 1.5, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

An `enumitem` attempt: a new counter representation command `\xalph` is defined and used which works the same as `\alph` except adds some space if counter has value 6.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\def\xalph#1{\expandafter\@xalph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@xalph#1{\ifnum#1=6\relax f\kern1pt\else\@alph{#1}\fi}

\AddEnumerateCounter\xalph\@xalph{m}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{label=(\xalph*).}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item a 1pt kern is inserted between \verb|f| and \verb|)|
    \item 
    \item 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this only possible in enumitem? For unspecified reasons, I must have the lettering lists in the tasks package.

Comment: @JackTigerLam Use `tasks` option `label={\xalph*}`.