# How to reformat "f" labelling in tasks package so the right side has more kerning space

Tags: kerning, tasks

I have a working solution to the problem posed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557186) for other packages such as enumitem, but I require a solution that works in the tasks package, which is not nearly as flexible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{csection}{RGB}{0,102,204}
\settasks{counter-format={(tsk[a])},
before-skip =-4pt,
label-format={\color{csection}
\fontsize{11pt}{11pt}%
\selectfont},
label-width={5ex}, item-indent={2.5em}, item-format={}, column-sep={3mm}, after-item-skip=1mm, after-skip=0mm
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}\item
\begin{tasks}(3)
          \task 1
          \task 2
          \task 3
          \task 4
          \task 5
          \task 6
        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Minimal example?

Comment: @egreg as you wish

Comment: With an up to date version of `tasks`you can do ```\newcommand*\myalph[1]{\alph{#1}\kern2\fontcharic\font\numexpr`a-1+\arabic{#1}\relax}``` and use `\begin{tasks}[label=(\myalph*)]`

Comment: @cgnieder I get a missing number error

Comment: @Jack I didn't. But your use of `\settasks{counter-format={(tsk[a])}` suggests that you are using an outdated version of `tasks` and my suggestion only works with an up to date version (as I said in my previous comment).

Comment: @cgnieder I don't know how to force overleaf to use the latest version.

Comment: @JackTigerLam I don't either but I'm sure the Overleaf support can help you with that